# using wget to download all audio files (over 100,000 pages on wikia)

Tags: wget

I am trying to download all audio files in Wookiepedia, the Star Wars wiki.

My first thought is something like this

```
wget -r -A  -nd .mp3 .ogg http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/
```

This should download all .mp3 and .ogg from the wiki while preventing creation of a directory. However, when I run this in terminal I get:

> bash: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/: No such file or directory

The problem is that I can't use for loops since the URLs are unique to each wiki page. For example:

```
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Retcon

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-3PX

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Legends
```

Is it possible to download URLs in this structure?

EDIT: This is the message I get back using the answer.

> --2016-02-10 16:21:26--  http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/
>   Resolving starwars.wikia.com (starwars.wikia.com)... 23.235.33.194, 23.235.37.194, 104.156.81.194, ...
>   Connecting to starwars.wikia.com (starwars.wikia.com)|23.235.33.194|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
>   Location: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page [following]
>   --2016-02-10 16:21:26--  http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page
>   Reusing existing connection to starwars.wikia.com:80.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: 569628 (556K) [text/html]
>   Saving to: ‘index.html’
>
> 100%[========================>] 569,628      217KB/s   in 2.6s
>
> 2016-02-10 16:21:29 (217 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [569628/569628]
>
> Removing index.html since it should be rejected.
>
> FINISHED --2016-02-10 16:21:29--
>   Total wall clock time: 2.7s
>   Downloaded: 1 files, 556K in 2.6s (217 KB/s)

```
sl
```

gives me nothing, there are no files in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply have the syntax slightly wrong. Try

```
wget -r -nd -A=mp3,ogg http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/
```

Comment: I suggest adding a delay. Besides netiquette, I bet a brute-force wget will kick-in anti DDos rules.

Comment: Thanks! This command doesn't work though, I download index.htm and then it's automatically deleted. Please see output above of command.

Comment: Yes, I got the 301 as well. But that's another ballpark and nothing to do with the original problem. Are you sure the base URL is http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/ and is correct?